# Create subscription or order in woocommerce after registration?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The concept is simple:

We would like woo commerce to automatically generate a predefined order for a customer once they register for our site (a membership site) and then be redirected to the checkout page to pay for the order.

The question is... Is this possible?

Comment: yes it is possible create the order and make that status been pending after that send a mail with `$order->get_checkout_payment_url` from order object, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is... Is this possible?

Yes, **it is possible** to make a pre-order when the registration is done and just link it to the checkout process.

How do i know? Im running an online shop, with some of the same feartures so im pretty sure that it is **possible**.

Altho i don't know why you want that, this must answer your question.